# Django-CMS admin tool Template

Tags: html, django, templates, content-management-system

I have created `html` template named `testTemplate` which is added to CMS_TEMPLATES:

```
CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ## Customize this
    ('fullwidth.html', 'Fullwidth'),
    ('sidebar_left.html', 'Sidebar Left'),
    ('sidebar_right.html', 'Sidebar Right'), 
    ('testTemplate.html', 'testTemplate')     
)
```

Then in `fullwidth.html` file I have changed the `{% extends "base.html" %}` to `{% extends "testTemplate.html" %}`. In `testTemplate.html` file I can find few `{% placehoders %}`. And now if I want to go to `django-cms` to add a content to placeholders, my cms-admin does not look right. Layout of `cms admin` looks like the template elements. How to separate the `cms-admin` template and my site template to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your issue.  Are you wanting to use testTemplate.html instead of base.html or are you wanting to insert testTemplate.html between base.html and fullwidth.html?

If you want to replace base.html, then I would simply save testTemplate.html in the same location as base.html and not bother registering it with CMS_TEMPLATES. Registering with CMS_TEMPLATES simply makes these templates available to your pages in cms-admin.  If testTemplate.html is not a final template that you will want to use then you don't need to register it here.  Note that base.html is not registered here for that very reason.  Another approach would be to rename base.html as something else and renaming testTemplate.html to base.html,  effectively replacing it if you don't want to use the original, which means you wouldn't need to change any of the dependant templates.

If you are trying to insert testTemplate.html between base.html and fullwidth.html, that is a different kettle of fish.  You will need to make sure you have all your blocks nested correctly and you'll need to post some more details like your html code for each page for people to be able to assist you.